# Sorting products into those with and without tags

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a shop that uses tags as holidays. e.g. Christmas. I have various products. Some are for the holidays and have a tag, and some are year-round and don't have tags. I would like it so that when entering the store's website or the category page, the products without tags would be displayed first, and then those with tags. I wrote this code, but it doesn't work. Nothing is displayed

````
function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args, $orderby, $order ) {    
    switch( $orderby ) {
        case 'product_tag':
            $args['orderby']  = 'meta_value';
            $args['meta_key'] = '_product_tag';
            $args['order']    = 'ASC';
            break;
    }

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 10, 3 );

// Orderby setting
function custom_orderby( $orderby ) {
    $orderby['product_tag'] = __( 'Sort by product tag', 'woocommerce' );
    return $orderby;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'custom_orderby', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_orderby', 10, 1 ); ```
````